# What are roots of higher power like $n^9=512$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

We know a value of $n$ in $n^2 = 4$ is $\pm2$ (two roots), then what about $n^9 = 512$, generic answer is $+2$, but it should have $9$ roots. What are those $8$ other roots and how can we find them ?

Comment: $x^2=-1$ has $2$ roots but they are not real.

Comment: See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%5B9%5D%7B512%7D).

Comment: @barakmanos, I have already given all the roots (Wolfram alpha). See my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Since $1=e^{2k\pi i}$ for any integer $k$, you can write

$$n = (512\cdot 1)^{1/9} = 512^{1/9}(e^{2k\pi i})^{1/9} = 2 e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{9}}, $$

for any integer $k$.  By Euler's formula this is

$$n = 2\left(\cos \frac{2k\pi i}{9} + i \sin \frac{2k\pi i}{9}\right) $$

and these complex numbers will all be different for $k= 0, 1, 2, \ldots, 8$,
giving you all 9 roots.

Comment: Is this method guaranteed to find all the roots of any higher power?

Comment: @Goldname Yes.  The method is 1.  Put the number in polar form.  2.  Take the positive nth root of the modulus.  3.  Divide the argument(s) by $n$.

Answer (score 2):

$2$ is not the only root here.The question is how to get all the roots in such a situation??

Here the concept of $nth$ roots of complex number work. Every number can be regarded as a complex number, If it is real just assume it to be a complex number having imaginary part$=0$

For the equation  $Z^n=z_0$ we have n roots which are:

> $Z_k = n\sqrt{r} (\cos \frac{\theta +2k\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{\theta +2k\pi}{n})$ where r is modulus of complex number.

[Here are](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots+of+n%5E9%3D512)  all the roots of your equation.

Comment: It's Tricky ,, what is this wolfram alfa @The Lone Wolf ???

Comment: Check the link I have given and you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

factorizing $$n^9-512$$ we get $$\left( n-2 \right)  \left( {n}^{2}+2\,n+4 \right)  \left( {n}^{6}+8\,
{n}^{3}+64 \right) 
$$ and from here you will get all solutions.

Comment: "and from here you will get all solutions" That is, assuming "you" have such a mathematical background that it is quite unlikely you would have asked this question in the first place... What an unhelpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$n^9-a^9=(n^3)^3-(a^3)^3=(n^3-a^3)(n^6+a^3n^3+a^6)=(n-a)(n^2+an+a^2)(n^6+a^3n^3+a^6)$$